# Excel File Downloaded From Blob Opens in Protected View

Tags: javascript, excel

I am trying to download an Excel file from my client using the `file-saver` JS library.

Currently, we hit an endpoint on the server to download the file. When it returns successfully, we use middle-ware to get the blob from the payload and then download it using `FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName)`.

Previously, we used an `iFrame` to accomplish this.

Using the `file-saver` library, the source URL is `blob:https://localhost:8080/...`

Previously, there was no `blob:` text at the beginning of the URL, and it seems this text is causing the excel file to open in "Protected View".

We have the url "https://localhost:8080/*" in the list of Excel's trusted sources, and opening the file works fine using an `iFrame`.

Is there any way to remove the `blob:` prefix or make this download open regularly?

Answer (score -1):

Its because of your local settings. You can follow this.

1. Open Excel file.
2. File--> Option --> Trust Center--> Trust center settings.
3. Trust locations--> Add "Download" folder path as trusted.

Any file open from this location is trusted by Excel hence "Enable Edit" option will not be shown. All formulas pre-applied.

[image]